# how to Json Deserialize jsonstring

Tags: c#, json-deserialization

i have a returned string looks like this

```
"{\"properties\":{\"item1\":{\"dataType\":\"string\"},\"item2\":{\"dataType\":\"string\"}},\"lastModified\":\"2021-12-09T18:20:29Z\"}"
```

i have tries to Deserialize by using dictionary but still not catching the data.
the most important data is just named inside the properties, **item1, item2**

```
System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IDictionary<string, object>>(jsonString)
```

and it' giving the folowing result

```
 [0] [KeyValuePair]:{[properties, {"Item1":{"dataType":"string"},"item2":{"dataType":"string"}
Key [string]:"properties"
Value [object]:ValueKind = Object : "{"item1":{"dataType":"string"},"item2":{"dataType":"string"}
Key [string]:"lastModified"
[1] [KeyValuePair]:{[lastModified, 2021-12-09T19:00:12Z]}
```

Comment: `and it' giving the folowing result` so what's the actual issue?

Comment: how to catch just the names ? item1 and item2 and so on into a list of strings

Comment: You might improve your question by providing an example of what you expect to get. From what you've shown, the deserialization is working correctly, but it sounds like you were expecting something different to happen.

Answer (score 1):

You can deserialize the JSON string to an object by following these simple steps:

1. Create a C# class from the JSON data. To do this, copy the JSON string and go to VS, Edit, Paste Special, Paste JSON as Classes.

if successful, you will get a C# class like this one

```
 public class Rootobject
{
    public Properties properties { get; set; }
    public DateTime lastModified { get; set; }
}

public class Properties
{
    public Item1 item1 { get; set; }
    public Item2 item2 { get; set; }
}

public class Item1
{
    public string dataType { get; set; }
}

public class Item2
{
    public string dataType { get; set; }
}
```

You can rename the classes to anything that make meaning to you.

The you can deserialize like this

```
 var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(
            "{\"properties\":{\"item1\":{\"dataType\":\"string\"},\"item2\":{\"dataType\":\"string\"}},\"lastModified\":\"2021-12-09T18:20:29Z\"}");

 Console.WriteLine(obj.properties.item2.dataType)// string
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the value of dataType property and not the whole object, than you can use Linq to Json to get it without deserialization and object mapping.

The examples:

```
var obj = JObject.Parse("{\"properties\":{\"item1\":{\"dataType\":\"string\"},\"item2\":{\"dataType\":\"string\"}},\"lastModified\":\"2021-12-09T18:20:29Z\"}");

var fistItemDataTypeValue = (string)obj["properties"]?["item1"]["dataType"];

var secondItemDataTypeValue = (string)obj["properties"]?["item2"]["dataType"];
```

Getting values as list of strings (*NOTES*: if you already know the number of items in json):

```
    var obj = JObject.Parse("{\"properties\":{\"item1\":{\"dataType\":\"string\"},\"item2\":{\"dataType\":\"string\"}},\"lastModified\":\"2021-12-09T18:20:29Z\"}");

    var listOfValues = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        listOfValues.Add((string)obj["properties"]?[$"item{i}"]["dataType"]);
    }
```

! More about [linq to json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/queryinglinqtojson.htm)